# Promise difference between chained .then and next function call

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

What's the difference between chained `.then` and next function call, for example:

```
funcThatReturnsPromise().then((a) => {

}).then(doSomething)
```

With

```
var b;
funcThatReturnsPromise().then((a) => {
   b = a;
});
doSomething(b);
```

*EDIT* I've tried it, it does the same:

```
var p2; var p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve(p2 = 'test1');
});
p1.catch(function(e){console.log('b',e)});
console.log('c',p2);
// result: c test1
```

vs

```
var p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve('test2');
});
p1.then(console.log).catch(function(e){console.log('b',e)});
// result: test2
```

Comment: it's the difference between knowing how asynchronous code works and not - i.e, b is undefined in the second code block

Comment: It's a matter of execution order. 

In your first example, the `then`s will be executed only when the previous promise is resolved, whenever this promise in sync or async.

In the second example, funcThatReturnsPromise will be executed almost at the same time than doSomething(b); and the `then` will *probably* be executed later. So, if doSomething is dependant of the result of funcThatReturnsPromise, you'll have to chain it. If it's totally independant, then you can execute it *at the same time*.